# CSS - Getting weird font rendering

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-fonts

I'm just doing the navbar and when I go to the browser all font families it render like this:

[Rendering like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox6DA.png)

Here is my code:

fonts.css:

```
 /* @font-face */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  src: '../fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf';
}
```

style.css:

```
    /* import fonts from fonts.css file */

@import url(./fonts.css);
@import url(./partials/variables.css);

/* Start Navigation */
.headerArea .mainMenu .navbar .navbar-brand {
  padding: 0 2rem 0 5rem;
}

.headerArea .mainMenu .navbar {
  padding: 1rem 15rem;
}

.headerArea .mainMenu .nav-item .nav-link {
  /*font-family: 'Roboto', cursive; */
  font-family: var(--roboto);
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 1.7rem;
  color: var(--title-color);
}

/* End Navigation */
```

variables.css:

```
 html,
body {
  margin: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* CSS Variables */

:root {
  --primary-color: #4458dc;
  --primary-color2: #854fee;
  --title-color: #141313;
  --text-color: #777777;
  --border-color: #201f1f17;
  --gradient-color: linear-gradient(90deg, #4458dc 0%, #854fee 100%);
  --primary-color: #4458dc;
  --primary-color: #4458dc;

  /* font family variables */
  --roboto: 'Roboto', cursive;
}
```

I tried more font families and they all got this aspect.
I'm using Bootstrap 5, dont know if that is a problem.

Comment: When you say it rendering weird that's not helping anyone to answer.

Comment: Sorry, i added an image

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in the fonts.css file. The font source should be written as follows, using parentheses:

```
src: url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf);
```